Multiple copies of 3-page multi label sequentially
I have to take 2 copies of 3-page label sequentially so that all the 3 pages will be printed before the copy starts. How can I write this code in ZPL - Zebra language?
This is a sample code.
I tried giving the ^PQ command and unfortunately it replicates the "Page 1" before printing "Page 2"
^XA
^FO50,50
^FDPage 1^FS
^XZ
^XA
^FO50,50
^A0N,50,50
^FDPage 2^FS
^XZ
^XA
^FO50,50
^A0N,50,50
^FDPage 3^FS
^XZ
The expected result -:
I need the print to come like "Page 1" -> "Page 2" -> "Page 3"  -> "Page 1" -> "Page 2" -> "Page 3"

ZPL does one-label-format-at-a-time rendering.  You will need to send the first three labels.  Then send them again.  Error handling can be tricky but it should work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
